# How to write multiple If statements in Spark UDF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My requirement is to create categories for age.I am trying to write multiple if conditions in UDF but its taking else condition. my code is below.

My data

```
1,Ashok,23,asd
2,Joi,27,dfs
3,Sam,30,dft
4,Bob,37,dat
```

my code

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import sqlContext.implicits._
val a = sc.textFile("file2.txt")
a.foreach(println)

val coder: (Int=>String)=(arg:Int)=>{if(arg>20&&arg<27) "20-27";if(arg>30&&arg<37) "30-37"; else "38+"}

val co = udf(coder)

val a2 = a1.select(col("Id"),col("Name"),col("Age"),col("Dpt"))

a2.withColumn("range",co(col("Age"))).show()
```

Output i am getting

```
1,Ashok,23,asd,38+
2,Joi,27,dfs,38+
3,Sam,30,dft,38+
4,Bob,37,dat,38+
```

For each row it is showing 38+, please suggest the syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using `if - else if - else` .

Also, you're skipping boundary values when you check for `arg>27 && arg<30`

Your UDF should look something like this :

```scala
val co = udf { (x: Int) => 
    if (x >= 20 && x <=27) "20-27"
    else if (x > 27 && x<=37 ) "28-37"
    else "38+" 
}

// co: org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,List(IntegerType))

df.withColumn("range" , co($"age" ) ).show

// +---+-----+---+---+-----+
// | id| name|age|dpt|range|
// +---+-----+---+---+-----+
// |  1|Ashok| 23|asd|20-27|
// |  2|  Joi| 27|dfs|28-37|
// |  3|  Sam| 30|dft|28-37|
// |  4|  Bob| 37|dat|  38+|
// +---+-----+---+---+-----+
```